# Python get name in loop

Tags: python, string, list

Hi guys i have multiple list with strings.
F.e.:

```
params = {
   "str1":"A Teststring which tests.",
   "str2":"Strings are awesome to test",
   "str3":"Teststring is a string that tests ",
   "str4":"String awesome test tests"
   }


erg =[]
allstrings = ['str1','str2','str3','str4']
userkeywords = ['teststring','awesome','test','string']
for str in allstrings:
    strkeywords = params[str].split()
    common = list(set(userkeywords) & set(strkeywords) )
    howmuch = len(common)
    erg.append(howmuch)
print erg
```

With this code i get how much words in the params string are the same. 
But how can i print out the strings which have the most words in common with the userkeywords.

Expectation:

```
str1 : 4
str2: 3
str4: 3
```

(numbers are examples)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different data-structure for `erg`, i.e a `dict`:

```
erg = {}
allstrings = ['str1','str2','str3','str4']
userkeywords = set(['teststring','awesome','test','string'])
for strs in allstrings:
    strkeywords = params[strs].split()
    #len() works on sets too, no need to convert this to a list
    common = len( userkeywords & set(strkeywords) )
    erg[str] = common

for k in sorted(erg, key=erg.get, reverse=True):
    print k, ':', erg[k]
```

**Output:**

```
str2 : 2
str4 : 2
str3 : 1
str1 : 0
```

Comment: Thank you both guys works perfect. How can i only print f.e. only the 3 best values? So that it will only print str2 str4 and str3 in this example

Comment: @user1477042 Yes, you can use slicing: `sorted(erg, key=erg.get, reverse=True)[:3]`